# Inserting long text description into database getting as failure in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have description field where i am inserting the description of a property.If i am entering the long text and submitting the data getting as failure.It is accepting only small text but in database i have changed the type to long text.

THis is my database table

Name             Type

property_id     int(11)
property_name   varchar(250)
Description     longtext

Query i have written like this:

```
<?php include 'db.php';
        if(isset($_POST['submit_user'])){   
        $ins_sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_properties(Description,property_name) 
        VALUES ('".$_POST['Description']."','".$_POST['property_name']."')";

        if(mysqli_query($conn,$ins_sql)){
            $msg = 'Successfully Created property';
            $msgclass='bg-success';                             
        }
        else{
            $msg = 'Failure';     
            $msgclass = 'bg-danger';
        }
        }
        ?>
```

HTML Code:

```
<form action="#" method="post"  role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php if($msg!=''){?>
                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                               <?php echo $msg;?>
                            </div>
                            <?php } ?>
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="field-label">Property Name</div>
                            <input type="text" name="property_name" id="property_name"  placeholder="Enter Property Name" required>
                        </div>                         
                      <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="field-label">Description</div>
                            <textarea name="Description" id="Description" placeholder="Enter Description" required></textarea>
                        </div>                           

                        <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> 
                                <div class="button-box">
                                    <button type="submit" class="theme-btn btn-style-one" name="submit_user" id="subject">SUBMIT</button> 
                                    <button type="cancel" class="theme-btn btn-style-one"><a href="https://weservice.in/weservice/Admin/property-list.php" class="cancel">CANCEL</a></button>
                                </div>
                  </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Use error reporting, https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php. Use parameterized queries as well.

Comment: Aside from your code being vulnerable to SQL injection, if you use any apostrophes in your description value, it would interrupt your query and caused it to fail. Like the previous commenter said, use parameterized queries / prepared statements to avoid this. There are several examples in the PHP documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with single quotes and double quotes as well.Now the data is inserting correctly into database with single quotes and double quotes as well.

Just Repalced the description query like this:

```
$description=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Description']);
```

$conn i have given my database link where i am storing my username password and db name.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your data contains illegal characters for your SQL (like `'` or `"`), try changing

```php
$ins_sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_properties(Description,property_name) 
        VALUES ('".$_POST['Description']."','".$_POST['property_name']."')";
```

for

```php
$ins_sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_properties(Description,property_name) 
        VALUES (".$_POST['Description'].",".$_POST['property_name'].")";
```

Comment: I have removed  like ' or " from the text then its working fine.No Need of changing code again

Comment: If i remove single quote or double quote its working fine but i have insert with quotations for that  so i have tried with this $description=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Description']);   and passed this variable while inserting the data it is showing as successfully inserted but the data is not inserting into description field